# Can't sync/backup directories between my pc and SD Card: Rsync Input/output error (5)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

My pc has 2 disk: 1 SSD (for the system) and 1 HDD (to store media, etc...)
I want to sync/backup between my HDD and my SD card, both are NTFS.

*When i start rsync for the first time and if i run the command without reboot or unmount the SD card, it works fine. But when i unmount the SD card and try to run rsync it starts.*

**Edit**: I did a new test (added video and music files) and it's even worse: it's always transferring all the content instead of the changes/differences, even on the firsts times.

Here is the test:

I ran:

```
rsync -hvr --delete /media/rfaz/Data/test/ /media/rfaz/KeinerSD/Backups/test2/
rsync -hvnr --delete /media/rfaz/Data/test/ /media/rfaz/KeinerSD/Backups/test2/
```

Also tried with `rsync -azhv` option but same result.

`tree` output of `/media/rfaz/Data/test/`

```
.
└── Dummy-dir-template
    ├── dummy-file-a.txt
    ├── dummy-file-b.txt
    ├── Images
    │   ├── IMG_20170219_205740.jpg
    │   ├── IMG_20170219_205749.jpg
    │   └── IMG_20170219_205906.jpg
    ├── Music
    │   ├── Una Mattina - ludovico Einaudi (Jimmy Sax Impro live).mp3
    │   └── Worakls - Blue ( Jimmy Sax live).mp3
    └── Videos
        ├── IMG_0001.MOV
        └── IMG_5377.mov
```

What is wrong with this?
How can i sync between my pc and my SD Card?

Comment: Have you tried to use `cp` to copy a file, just try to see where the problem lies ?

Comment: I was navigating in my SD card via CLI and there are some folders that gave this error when doing `ls`: ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error  . So maybe my SD card has some problems (it's a brand new sandisk so this is strange)

Comment: Ok just performed a disk check and the sd card filesystem is damaged